# ASP.MVC Windows Authentication HTTP Error 401. The requested resource requires user authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET MVC application using windows authentication that I published by visual studio on a windows 2008 server.

But when I try to reach the application from a browser I have to authenticate I get the default authentication form to do this.

If I type my user name and password I can not reach my application but if I use the administration account the application will be displayed in the browser.

And other strange things... in the IIS server I select the application site and click basic settings.

I click on the test connection button I get the following error message:

"Invalid application path".

But if I click the connect as button and use the administration account the test is passed successfully.

Anybody can help me?

l.

Comment: See my MSDN How to Create an Intranet Site Using ASP.NET MVC article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(VS.98).aspx - you should test this on your Windows 7/local IIS server before deploying. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx

Comment: Are you sure the server is joined to the domain?